# what's the meaning of such mysql rpms

Tags: mysql, c, linux

rpm -qa on my host,i see:

```
mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
```

but i still cant see mysql.h and mysql.so in the lib and include dir.so i google and see other two rpm:

```
mysql-server-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
mysql-devel-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
mysql-client-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
```

so

1)what's the meaning of these rpms?to me,mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 should have the *.so an *.a files installed,but i cant see them on the host?

2. "yum list installed mysql*" says nothing installed,but "rpm -qa" can see msyql rpms?what the diff of these two cmds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- mysql is the command line client

  - mysql-client is the same thing for Mandriva
- mysql-libs are the shared libraries required for MySQL *clients*
- mysql-server is the MySQL server
- mysql-devel are the header files required to develop (compile) MySQL applications